# Eclipse-Views put to second display is reset on osx-Maverick on Eclipse restart

Tags: osx-mavericks, eclipse-luna

I'm working with an imac on OS 10.9.5 Maverick and Eclipse Luna. A second Display is installed and working fine.
It is no problem to put a view, for example the console to the second display. When I switch the perspective or restart eclipse the the console is thrown back to the display were eclipse is shown.

I'm not familiar with mac osx but I have seen that it works fine on colleague's mac with 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion?).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Does nobody knows how to solve it or isn't the explanation detailed enough?

Comment: Your question seems to be off-topic for this site: it's probably the reason why nobody answers it. [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)